# mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting <SERVER_IP>:/mount/test

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

Have a strange issue with mounting an NFS share.

Server: OS Debian 9.
/etc/exports:

```
/var/www    <CLIENT_IP>(rw,sync,fsid=fd095945-8ace-4f31-b349-91bf805ca2ea,no_root_squash,crossmnt,insecure,no_subtree_check)
/mount/test <CLIENT_IP>(rw,sync,no_root_squash,crossmnt,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

showmount -e:

```
/mount/test <CLIENT_IP>
/var/www    <CLIENT_IP>
```

Client: Ubuntu 14.04 with latest updates, while try to mount any of existing share - getting an error:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting <CLIENT_IP>:/mount/test
```

The strange (for me) next thing: I can mount share like this:

```
mount <SERVER_IP>:/ /mnt/nfs
```

/mnt/nfs now has a subdirectories which exported on a server, but when I try to enter a directory in /mnt/nfs got an error:

```
bash: cd: mount/: Permission denied
```

Can anyone advance me?

Comment: The 'access denied' error message - shouldn't that be `SERVER-IP:/mount/test` ? Also, are there additional exports on the server you haven't mentioned here?

Comment: I provide a full list of exported filesystems. Yes, seems there a SERVER_IP, i just misspelled.

Comment: Very strange but I am successfully mount FS on working laptop, seems problem in  NFS versions mismatches... I just try to upgrade a test ubuntu client machine and then write here results.

Comment: You can force the version from the client by specifying the mount option `nfsvers=4.0`.